# Is it possible in mysql to use IN statement with varchar column

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in mysql to use IN statement with varchar column

In my case

```
SELECT `custids` FROM user WHERE id = 1;
```

It returns custids column which is varchar and values are comma seperated like 1,2,3

When I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user.id IN(`custids`);
```

It is not running like I expected.

Actually I am to run query like :

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user.id IN(1,2,3);
```

But I think it is running like :

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user.id IN('1,2,3');
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id in(SELECT custids FROM user WHERE id = 1);`

Comment: If you have any chance to change the database layout, do so. Databases are not intended to be used in that way; no optimization will be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unable to build query with 1,2,3 instead of '1,2,3' you may try to use FIND_IN_SET

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
 SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user.id, '1,2,3') IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: +0.5 (well that doesn't work, so +1): It is a perfect answer to the question. But it can only be a workaround for a badly designed database. Once the amount of data grows, this stuff will bite you.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user.id in('1','2','3');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Question was ,Can we use or not ? rather then finding an alternate?
As in my query i am using `CASE` clause:-

```
case
when customer_location.city in('bangalore','Mumbai')
              then cond1
              else cond2
              end
```

So it works with Varchar also but u need to write within double quotes.